# How to scroll a parent div horizontally to match edges with child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of tab nodes as a child of a parent. When a tab becomes active, I want to ensure it is visible, so the parent div must be scrolled at least enough to make the child div fully visible.

What I have is somewhat similar to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdniki/4eqCH/), except basically each block of four letters is a separate child node.

How is this done? CommonJs or jQuery solutions both fine with me.

Pseudo-code:

```
var childOffset = parentPosition - childPosition;
$('.parent').scrollLeft(childOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with these:

```
jQuery('.parent').animate({
        scrollLeft: jQuery('.child').offset().left
},1000);

jQuery('.parent').animate({
        scrollLeft: jQuery('.child').position().left
},1000);

jQuery('.parent').animate({
        scrollLeft: jQuery('.child').width() * 2
},0);
```

Comment: I don't always want to scroll though. I only want to scroll if the child is not fully visible. The parent container scrolls with `overflow:scroll`